# How do I list all pods controlled by deployments only?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

i would like to list all pods of a specific namespace but only those that are controlled by deployment
i have tried this but didn't succeed:
`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o json | jq -r '.items | map(select(.metadata.ownerReferences == deployment ) | .metadata.name) | .[]'`

I use this command:
`kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.namespace}{"\t"}{.spec.containers[*].name}{"\n"}{end}' --all-namespaces |sed 's/\t/\'$'\\/g' | sort | uniq`
to list all containers and their namespaces so i want the same but filtering out all non-deployments kind

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubectl command to list pods of a deployment in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52957227/kubectl-command-to-list-pods-of-a-deployment-in-kubernetes)

Comment: Thank you Amit but no, i am looking to list all pods that are controlled by deployments and not by other controllers like stateful set, etc...
no labels

Comment: Deployments don't create pods directly. Instead they create replica sets, and replica sets create pods. That means that the ownerReference will always be a replica set for pods managed by a deployment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--custom-columns` to find out which pods are controlled, and which kind of controller is the owner. Example:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,CONTROLLER:.metadata.ownerReferences[].kind,NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace
NAME                                        CONTROLLER   NAMESPACE
nginx-858dbf7665-8t9vv                      ReplicaSet   default
coredns-74ff55c5b-xpgnq                     ReplicaSet   kube-system
etcd-minikube                               Node         kube-system
ingress-nginx-admission-create-n6j7k        Job          kube-system
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-45xvw         Job          kube-system
ingress-nginx-controller-65cf89dc4f-g7lwm   ReplicaSet   kube-system
kindnet-44pq8                               DaemonSet    kube-system
kindnet-nqhg9                               DaemonSet    kube-system
kube-apiserver-minikube                     Node         kube-system
kube-controller-manager-minikube            Node         kube-system
kube-proxy-nmzbn                            DaemonSet    kube-system
kube-proxy-wlmdz                            DaemonSet    kube-system
kube-scheduler-minikube                     Node         kube-system
metrics-server-58966dd6b9-schjr             ReplicaSet   kube-system
storage-provisioner                         <none>       kube-system
```

---

Remember that *Deployments* automatically creates *ReplicaSets* and rely on them to manage a set of pods and its desired state/replicas. So you can just filter them:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o json | jq -r '.items | map(select(.metadata.ownerReferences[]?.kind == "ReplicaSet" ) | .metadata.name) | .[]'
nginx-858dbf7665-8t9vv
coredns-74ff55c5b-xpgnq
ingress-nginx-controller-65cf89dc4f-g7lwm
metrics-server-58966dd6b9-schjr
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,CONTROLLER:.metadata.ownerReferences[].kind,NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace` didn't work for me giving below error

zsh: no matches found: custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,CONTROLLER:.metadata.ownerReferences[].kind,NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace

Instead this worked fine -
`kubectl get pods -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace,Component:.metadata.ownerReferences\[\].kind`

Comment: I received the same error and your solution worked. Thanks.